# How to align multicolumn and cmidrule and get a nice long table in booktabs?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, booktabs

can someone help me with aligning my table using multicolumn and cmidrule. I have a long table with 19 columns and used \tiny to get the table on the page, but the lay out is not so nice. I want something like the second image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}% raggedleft column X

\begin{table}[htbp]
\tiny
  \centering
  \caption{ARMA order selection}
  \begin{tabular}{*{19}{l}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DJI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NIKKEI} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TSX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FTSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DAX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAC} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BVSP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{HSI} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
    \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
    \cmidrule(lr){14-15}
    \cmidrule(lr){16-17}
    \cmidrule(lr){18-19}
    & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC \\
    \midrule
    ARMA(1,0) & 4936.9 & 4952.8 & 5288.5 & 5304.4 & 4528.1 & 4544.0 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.8 & 5242.3 & 5258.2 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6153.9 & 6169.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8  \\
    ARMA(0,1) & 4944.3 & 4960.3 & 5288.6 & 5304.6 & 4533.6 & 4549.5 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.9 & 5242.4 & 5258.3 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6154.8 & 6170.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 &\\
    ARMA(1,1) & 4922.0 & 4943.3 & 5285.5 & 5306.8 & 4506.4 & 4527.6 & 4735.0 & 4756.2 & 5314.8 & 5336.1 & 5244.0 & 5265.3 & 5590.6 & 5611.9 & 6155.5 & 6176.8 & 4969.9 & 4991.2 &\\
    ARMA(2,1) & 4922.7 & 4949.3 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4506.0 & 4532.5 & 4735.2 & 4761.7 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.4 & 5271.1 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3  &\\
    ARMA(1,2) & 4922.7 & 4949.2 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4505.9 & 4532.5 & 4735.3 & 4761.9 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.2 & 5270.8 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 &\\
    ARMA(2,2) & 4919.3 & 4951.2 & 5289.3 & 5321.2 & 4505.7 & 4537.6 & 4719.1 & 4751.0 & 5316.8 & 5348.7 & 5233.9 & 5265.8 & 5594.0 & 5625.9 & 6157.0 & 6188.9 & 4966.2 & 4998.1 &\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Selection of ARMA orders}
\end{table}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepar a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use to reproduce the output you get. If I try to build such a MWE based on the information your provided so far, I end up with a remarkably different output.

Comment: Also, you declare a total of 19 columns and seem to need exactly 19 columns, but some of your table rows contin an extra `&` right before the `\\ ` which should cause an error message. Remove the extra `&`s.

Comment: What do you mean with `the lay out is not so nice`? You can try removing the `&` in `&\\\`  for better alignment ...

Comment: I have added an image for the lay out I prefer

Comment: Please point out the specific differences between your table and the expected layout. What exactly do you want to change about your table?

Comment: Please also add the documentclass you currently use to your MWE. Do you use the `geometry` package? If so, include the corresponding settings, as well.

Comment: I want the same cmidrule and multicolumn allignment and also want the same space between the columns if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering the AIC and BIC and using `\arraystretch` helps a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=30cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\SH}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{AIC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BIC}} % subhead
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\tiny
  \centering
  \setlength{\abovetopsep}{10pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \caption{ARMA order selection}
  \begin{tabular}{*{19}{l}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DJI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NIKKEI} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TSX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FTSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DAX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAC} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BVSP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{HSI} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
    \cmidrule(lr){12-13}
    \cmidrule(lr){14-15}
    \cmidrule(lr){16-17}
    \cmidrule(lr){18-19}
    & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH & \SH \\
    \midrule
    ARMA(1,0) & 4936.9 & 4952.8 & 5288.5 & 5304.4 & 4528.1 & 4544.0 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.8 & 5242.3 & 5258.2 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6153.9 & 6169.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8  \\
    ARMA(0,1) & 4944.3 & 4960.3 & 5288.6 & 5304.6 & 4533.6 & 4549.5 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.9 & 5242.4 & 5258.3 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6154.8 & 6170.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 \\
    ARMA(1,1) & 4922.0 & 4943.3 & 5285.5 & 5306.8 & 4506.4 & 4527.6 & 4735.0 & 4756.2 & 5314.8 & 5336.1 & 5244.0 & 5265.3 & 5590.6 & 5611.9 & 6155.5 & 6176.8 & 4969.9 & 4991.2 \\
    ARMA(2,1) & 4922.7 & 4949.3 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4506.0 & 4532.5 & 4735.2 & 4761.7 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.4 & 5271.1 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    ARMA(1,2) & 4922.7 & 4949.2 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4505.9 & 4532.5 & 4735.3 & 4761.9 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.2 & 5270.8 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    ARMA(2,2) & 4919.3 & 4951.2 & 5289.3 & 5321.2 & 4505.7 & 4537.6 & 4719.1 & 4751.0 & 5316.8 & 5348.7 & 5233.9 & 5265.8 & 5594.0 & 5625.9 & 6157.0 & 6188.9 & 4966.2 & 4998.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Selection of ARMA orders}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to explicitly mention that you drastically increased the paper size in order to get the table to fit.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compilable, replace `& \\`  with `\\` . Otherwise, you end up with the error message `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`. Once you get an error message, don't look at the resulting pdf file, but ix the error first.

Now that the code compiles properly, we can take a look at the output and see that the table is, even with a `\tiny` font size, still far too wide to fit onto the page. I therefore suggest splitting it up. I additionally changed the horizontal alignment from left aligned to centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{ARMA order selection}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{6}{c}}
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DJI}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NIKKEI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TSX} 
 \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC  \\
    \midrule
    ARMA(1,0) & 4936.9 & 4952.8 & 5288.5 & 5304.4 & 4528.1 & 4544.0 \\
    ARMA(0,1) & 4944.3 & 4960.3 & 5288.6 & 5304.6 & 4533.6 & 4549.5 \\
    ARMA(1,1) & 4922.0 & 4943.3 & 5285.5 & 5306.8 & 4506.4 & 4527.6 \\
    ARMA(2,1) & 4922.7 & 4949.3 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4506.0 & 4532.5 \\
    ARMA(1,2) & 4922.7 & 4949.2 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4505.9 & 4532.5 \\
    ARMA(2,2) & 4919.3 & 4951.2 & 5289.3 & 5321.2 & 4505.7 & 4537.6 \\
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FTSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DAX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAC}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC  \\
    \midrule
    ARMA(1,0)  & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.8 & 5242.3 & 5258.2  \\
    ARMA(0,1)  & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.9 & 5242.4 & 5258.3  \\
    ARMA(1,1)  & 4735.0 & 4756.2 & 5314.8 & 5336.1 & 5244.0 & 5265.3  \\
    ARMA(2,1)  & 4735.2 & 4761.7 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.4 & 5271.1  \\
    ARMA(1,2)  & 4735.3 & 4761.9 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 & 5244.2 & 5270.8  \\
    ARMA(2,2)  & 4719.1 & 4751.0 & 5316.8 & 5348.7 & 5233.9 & 5265.8  \\
    \midrule
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSE}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BVSP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{HSI} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC \\
    \midrule
    ARMA(1,0) & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6153.9 & 6169.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 \\
    ARMA(0,1) & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6154.8 & 6170.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 \\
    ARMA(1,1) & 5590.6 & 5611.9 & 6155.5 & 6176.8 & 4969.9 & 4991.2 \\
    ARMA(2,1) & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    ARMA(1,2) & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    ARMA(2,2) & 5594.0 & 5625.9 & 6157.0 & 6188.9 & 4966.2 & 4998.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Selection of ARMA orders}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
%  \small
  \caption{ARMA order selection}
  \begin{tabular}{l*{10}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DJI} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{NIKKEI} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TSX} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{FTSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DAX} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
    \cmidrule(l){10-11}
    ARMA & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC  \\
    \midrule
    (1,0) & 4936.9 & 4952.8 & 5288.5 & 5304.4 & 4528.1 & 4544.0 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.8 \\
    (0,1) & 4944.3 & 4960.3 & 5288.6 & 5304.6 & 4533.6 & 4549.5 & 4733.0 & 4748.9 & 5312.9 & 5328.9 \\
    (1,1) & 4922.0 & 4943.3 & 5285.5 & 5306.8 & 4506.4 & 4527.6 & 4735.0 & 4756.2 & 5314.8 & 5336.1 \\
    (2,1) & 4922.7 & 4949.3 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4506.0 & 4532.5 & 4735.2 & 4761.7 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 \\
    (1,2) & 4922.7 & 4949.2 & 5287.3 & 5313.9 & 4505.9 & 4532.5 & 4735.3 & 4761.9 & 5314.0 & 5340.6 \\
    (2,2) & 4919.3 & 4951.2 & 5289.3 & 5321.2 & 4505.7 & 4537.6 & 4719.1 & 4751.0 & 5316.8 & 5348.7 \\
    \midrule
    &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{CAC} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{BVSP} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{HSI} \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(l){8-9}
    ARMA & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC & AIC & BIC \\
    \midrule
    (1,0) & 5242.3 & 5258.2 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6153.9 & 6169.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 \\
    (0,1) & 5242.4 & 5258.3 & 5588.9 & 5604.9 & 6154.8 & 6170.8 & 4967.9 & 4983.8 \\
    (1,1) & 5244.0 & 5265.3 & 5590.6 & 5611.9 & 6155.5 & 6176.8 & 4969.9 & 4991.2 \\
    (2,1) & 5244.4 & 5271.1 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    (1,2) & 5244.2 & 5270.8 & 5592.3 & 5618.9 & 6157.5 & 6184.1 & 4970.7 & 4997.3 \\
    (2,2) & 5233.9 & 5265.8 & 5594.0 & 5625.9 & 6157.0 & 6188.9 & 4966.2 & 4998.1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Selection of ARMA orders}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great, however when i use this code i still get no space between the columns. Is that because i have used tabularx somewhere else?

Comment: Did you try to compile my code as it is or did you include the table into your actual document? The use of `tabularx` isn't related to the issue, but I guess, you somewhere reduced the value of `\tabcolsep` using  `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}` or something similar. Is that the case?

Comment: yes I used the \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}, however when i change it to tabularx i almost got the table you presented however the cmidrule isn't aligned like yours.

Comment: Don't use `tabularx` for the table at hand, especially not, if there is no `X` type column involved. Instead, either remove the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}` or, if you need it for some resaon for a different table, make sure it is limited to this particular table only.

Comment: It worked thank you very much!